# Integrate providing incorrect result for complex exponentials

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the integral
\[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(e^{iax}-1)(e^{ibx}-1)}{x^2}\quad a,b\in\mathbb R\]
which can be manually computed to be $\pi|\text{sgn}(a)-\text{sgn}(b)|\min(|a|,|b|)$.

However when plugging this into mathematica, we get something completely different:

```
Integrate[((E^(I a x) - 1) (E^(I b x) - 
    1))/x^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals]
```

outputs

\[\frac{1}{2} \left(i \left(a \log \left(a^2\right)+i \pi  \left| a+b\right| -a \log \left((a+b)^2\right)-b \log \left((a+b)^2\right)-i \pi  \left| b\right| +b \log \left(b^2\right)\right)+\pi  \left| a\right| -2 (a+b) \left(\pi -i \log \left(\frac{a+b}{b}\right)\right)+2 i a \log (b)-2 i a \log (a)\right)\]

which can be simplified to

\[\frac{1}{2} \pi  (-\left| a+b\right| +\left| a\right| -2 a+\left| b\right| -2 b)\]

and if we restrict ourselves to $a,b>0$,

```
Integrate[((E^(I a x) - 1) (E^(I b x) - 
    1))/x^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]
```

outputs

\[-(a+b)\pi\]

which is clearly off. In this case we can immediately see the integral must be $0$ by considering a semi-circular contour on the upper half plane.

I've found three ways to get Mathematica to output the correct result:

### Using PrincipalValue

```
Integrate[((E^(I a x) - 1) (E^(I b x) - 
    1))/x^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]
```

outputs

\[\begin{cases} -2 \pi  a & a<0\land a+b\geq 0 \\ 2 \pi  a & a\geq 0\land a+b<0 \\ -2 \pi  b & b<0\land a+b\geq 0 \\ 2 \pi  b & b\geq 0\land a+b<0 \\\end{cases}\]

### Expanding the complex exponential

The real part

```
Integrate[(
 1 - Cos[a x] - Cos[b x] + Cos[a x] Cos[b x] - 
  Sin[a x] Sin[b x])/x^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals]
```

gives

\[\pi  (-\left| a+b\right| +\left| a\right| +\left| b\right| )\]

while the imaginary part

```
Integrate[(-Sin[a x] + Cos[b x] Sin[a x] - Sin[b x] + 
  Cos[a x] Sin[b x])/x^2, {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals && b \[Element] Reals]
```

gives $0$.

### Providing explicit values for $a,b$

Simply throwing in values for $a,b$ gives the correct result, not the nicest but works if we only need a specific case.

Why exactly is specifying `PrincipalValue -> True` or expanding the complex exponentials necessaary? afaik `PrincipalValue` only matters when there is some branch cut/poles but these shouldn't be present in this integral?

Comment: `PrincipalValue -> True` uses a different approach to compute the integral than the one used without it.  That they give different results means one of them is in error.  You should report it to WRI. (Does this answer your question?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Icic I'll report it there instead!

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple 2021 `VectorCalculus:-int((exp(a*x*I) - 1)*(exp(b*x*I) - 1)/x^2, x = -infinity .. infinity)assuming a::real,b::real` performs a correct result `-a*signum(0, a + b, 0)*Pi - b*signum(0, a + b, 0)*Pi + a*signum(0, a, 0)*Pi + b*signum(0, b, 0)*Pi`.

Comment: `signum(0,x,0)` is `Sign[x]`.

Comment: -((a+b) \[Pi])  is still there, but the very first Integrate is now much more simple.